# Smallest angle of a triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles, maxima-minima

> What is the smallest angle of a triangle with $area=40cm^2$ and one side $=12cm$?

I am stuck before i get started Please help me.

Comment: $$40=\dfrac{12b\sin C}2\le6b$$  For $C=90^\circ,$ $$b=\dfrac{40}6,\tan A=\dfrac{12}{\dfrac{40}6},\tan B=\cot A=?$$

Comment: So what? ...........

Comment: The smallest angle of that triangle can be as small as you want. It can be one degree, one-tenth of one degree, one-hundredth of one degree, ....

Answer (score 3):

Imagine fixing the 12cm side of the triangle horizontally; call it the base. Now since the area of a triangle is determined by its base and height, the area condition fixes the height of the third point. We can still move the third point around horizontally without changing the base and area. What happens to the angles when we move that point around?

Answer (score 1):

Altitude is $CO =6\frac23$, base is $AB=12$, $C$ goes to $\infty$ parallel to $AB,$ so that lines $ AC,BC $ coincide, is the *limit solution narrow triangle* of zero angle at vertex $C$ and area $ 40$.

[image]